# Java Tic Tac Toe constructors

Tags: java

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db3cC5iPrOM

at 2:59 I couldn't understand what he is saying.

I don't get it why he creates a constructor(new TicTacToe();) inside a constructor(public static void main(String args[])

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    new TicTacToe();
}

public TicTacToe(){
    super("TicTacToe");
}
```

Can't we use do it this way? what's the difference?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    super("TicTacToe");
}
```

Comment: main is a static method. Its not a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super` means: call the parent's constructor in the case of inheritance. You have to call `new` to create an instance of `TicTacToe` in your main method if you want to use the `TicTacToe` class.

You may need to learn about ***inheritance*** and ***polymorphism*** before you follow this tutorial any further.

**BaseTicTacToe** - *base class*

```
public class BaseTicTacToe {
    private String name;

    public BaseTicTacToe(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**TicTacToe** - *child class*

```
public class TicTacToe extends BaseTicTacToe {
    public TicTacToe() {
        super("TicTacToe");
    }
}
```

**TicTacToeDriver**

```
public class TicTacToeDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTacToe(); // Instatiate a new TicTacToe instance.
    }
}
```

---

You may also see the following where you call another constructor inside the current class.

```
public class TicTacToe {
    private String name;        

    // Default constructor.
    public TicTacToe() {
        this("TicTacToe"); // Call the constructor below.
    }

    // Overloaded constructor (polymorphism)
    public TicTacToe(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TicTacToe();          // Call default:  "TicTacToe"
        new TicTacToe("My Name"); // Call overload: "My Name"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`main` is not a constructor, it's a static method which is the entry point to your application.  Since it's a static method, you don't need to create an instance of the class to call it.

You can only call the `super` to invoke a superclass's constructor within the superclass constructor, and since `main` isn't a constructor, your second code example is not valid.